# Tour of Go exercise #18: Slices, index out of range

Tags: go

I am working through the exercises in the Go tour and I have hit a snag that I can't figure out.

I'm doing [`Exercise: Slices`](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/18) and I am getting this error:

```
256 x 256

panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.Pic(0x100, 0x100)
    /tmp/sandbox1628012103/prog.go:14 +0xcf
golang.org/x/tour/pic.Show(0xc0000001a0)
    /tmp/gopath962180923/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tour@v0.0.0-20201207214521-004403599411/pic/pic.go:32 +0x28
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox1628012103/prog.go:25 +0x25
```

Here is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/tour/pic"
)

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    fmt.Printf("%d x %d\n\n", dx, dy)

    pixels := make([][]uint8, 0, dy)

    for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
        pixels[y] = make([]uint8, 0, dx)

        for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
            pixels[y][x] = uint8(x * y)
        }
    }

    return pixels
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459474/go-tour-slices-exercise-logic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slices)
>
> For a string, array, pointer to array, or slice a, the primary
>   expression
>
> a[low : high]
>
> constructs a substring or slice. The index expressions low and high
>   select which elements appear in the result. The result has indexes
>   starting at 0 and length equal to high - low.
>
> For arrays or strings, the indexes low and high must satisfy 0 <= low
>   <= high <= length; for slices, the upper bound is the capacity rather
>   than the length.
>
> [Indexes](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Indexes)
>
> A primary expression of the form
>
> a[x]
>
> denotes the element of the array, slice, string or map a indexed by x.
>   The value x is called the index or map key, respectively. The
>   following rules apply:
>
> For a of type A or *A where A is an array type, or for a of type S
>   where S is a slice type:
>
> ```
> x must be an integer value and 0 <= x < len(a)
>
> a[x] is the array element at index x and the type of a[x] is
> the element type of A
>
> if a is nil or if the index x is out of range, a run-time panic occurs
> ```
>
> [Making slices, maps and channels](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)
>
> ```
> make(T, n)       slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity n
> make(T, n, m)    slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity m
> ```

y must be an integer value and 0 <= y < len(pixel[]uint8). x must be an integer value and 0 <= x < len(pixel[][]uint8). For example,

```
package main

import "tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    pixels := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
        pixels[y] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
            pixels[y][x] = uint8(x * y)
        }
    }
    return pixels
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Comment: So make([]uint8, dx) makes a slice with dx zeros in it?  If that's the case how is that different than capacity? I mean if I do make([]uint8, 0, dx) wouldn't that create a slice that can hold up to dx uint8s but us currently empty?

Comment: See my answer. `make([]uint8, dx)` is equivalent to `make([]uint8, dx, dx)` i.e. len()= dx and cap() = dx, which is not the same as `make([]uint8, 0, dx)` i.e. len() = 0 and cap() = dx. In both cases the underlying array is cap() = dx zero value elements. Indices must be 0 <= i < len(), otherwise a run-time panic occurs.

Answer (score -2):

```
package main

import "tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
fmt.Printf("%d x %d\n\n", dx, dy)

     pixels := make([][]uint8, 0, dy)

       for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
    //    pixels[y] = make([]uint8, 0, dx)

for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
 // append can skip make statement   
 pixels[y] = append(pixels[y],uint8(x*y)) 

     }
}

 return pixels
}

 func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
 }
```

Comment: Code only answers without any description or explanation of what changes were made or why are not very helpful.