# difference between declaring variables with var vs without var in go

Tags: go, indexoutofboundsexception

I was having some trouble with [step 35 in the tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/#35) exercise.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
package main

import "code.google.com/p/go-tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    var pic = make([][]uint8, dy)
    for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
        pic[y] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for x := 0; y < dx; x++ {
            pic[y][x] = uint8(x*y)
        } 
    }
    return pic
}
```

When looking for a solution, I found [PeterSO's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585008/go-tour-excerciseslices-index-out-of-range#answer-11585467) code which works perfectly

```
func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    pixels := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
        pixels[y] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
            pixels[y][x] = uint8(x * y)
        }
    }
    return pixels
}
```

The only difference I can see, is that I'm defining the `pic` variable using the `var` keyword whereas his code is using the `:=` assignment. Now, why does my code not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `:=`, the type of the variable is implied from the expression on the right of the sign. If you use `=`, no assumption is made and you need to specify the type yourself.

In this case, you should write it like this:

```
var pic [][]uint8 = make([][]uint8, dy)
```

but this is indeed better because shorter and as clear:

```
pic := make([][]uint8, dy)
```

Comment: `var pic = make([][]uint8, dy)` is valid, and the type is inferred. Don't write `var pic [][]uint8 = make([][]uint8, dy)`, repeating the type is redundant.

Comment: @Laurent: Not true, type inference works with `=` as well: `var v = expr`.

Comment: In addition, I think you cannot use `:=` outside a function definition, to make it global, you must use `var` in that case.

Comment: Yeah, this answer isn't correct at all. And I wouldn't say that `:=` is "indeed better". It's not as visible. I've seen bugs crop up in my code as well as others that came about from shadowing a variable because `:=` was used, which is harder to spot.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote

```
for x := 0; y < dx; x++ {
    pic[y][x] = uint8(x * y)
}
```

in particular: `y < dx`, which causes,

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

I wrote

```
    for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
        pixels[y][x] = uint8(x * y)
    }
```

in particular: `x < dx`. Therefore, change your `y` to `x`.

```
package main

import "code.google.com/p/go-tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    var pic = make([][]uint8, dy)
    for y :=0; y < dy; y++ {
        pic[y] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for x :=0; x<dx; x++ {
            pic[y][x] = uint8(x*y)
        } 
    }
    return pic
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/UvGgszFhl-

[image: go tour slices]

> [Variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)
>
> A variable declaration creates a variable, binds an identifier to it
>   and gives it a type and optionally an initial value.
>
> ```
> VarDecl     = "var" ( VarSpec | "(" { VarSpec ";" } ")" ) .
> VarSpec     = IdentifierList ( Type [ "=" ExpressionList ] | "=" ExpressionList ) .
> ```
>
> [Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)
>
> A short variable declaration uses the syntax:
>
> `ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList` .
>
> It is a shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer
>   expressions but no types:
>
> ```
> "var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .
> ```
>
> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank
>   variables is new.

In your code `var pic = make([][]uint8, dy)` and the short form `pic := make([][]uint8, dy)` will both work.