# Tour of Go exercise #18: Slices

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to complete the [`Exercise: Slices` from the Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/18).
However I don't really understand what I'm being asked to do.

> Implement Pic. It should return a slice of length dy, each element of which is a slice of dx 8-bit unsigned integers. When you run the program, it will display your picture, interpreting the integers as grayscale (well, bluescale) values.

I have the following code

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    a := make([][]uint8, dy)
    return a
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

I have created the slice of length dy so far. However I don't understand the next step. Do I need to create a for loop in which I assign every element of my slice to a value in the range of dx?  I don't ask for code but rather for an explanation/clarification

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Do I need to create a for loop in which I assign every element of my slice to a value in the range of dx?

Yes:

- an outer loop to assign a[x] with a `[]uint8` slice of `dx` size,
- with an inner loop '`y`' for each element `a[x]` (which is a `[]uint8`) in order to assign `a[x][y]` with the asked value (ie, one of the "interesting functions" like `x^y`, `(x+y)/2`, and `x*y`).
  `x` and `y` are indexes in a range over a slice (`a`, then `a[x]`): see "[`For` statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)".

I like `(x ^ y) * (x ^ y)`:

[image: res]

As [rwilson04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533209/rwilson04) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459474/go-tour-slices-exercise-logic/25459513?noredirect=1#comment60546839_25459513):

> `x*x + y*y` is another good one

[image: x square plus y square]

[Waqas Ilyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987519/waqas-ilyas) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459474/go-tour-slices-exercise-logic/25459513?noredirect=1#comment118453017_25459513): `y * 10000 / (x + 1)`

[image: y * 10000 / (x + 1)]

[EdvardM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289420/edvardm) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459474/tour-of-go-exercise-18-slices/25459513#comment136859361_25459513): `(x+y)/2 * (x^y)`:

[image: (x+y)/2 * (x^y)]

[Chubby Cows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16910396/chubby-cows) proposes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459474/tour-of-go-exercise-18-slices#comment137823135_25459513): `((x - y) * -1) * (x + y) / 2`:

[image: ((x - y) * -1) * (x + y) / 2]

Comment: @rwilson04 Nice! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as added the resulting picture from `x*x + y*y`

Comment: Random comment, but you can use `<<` in your "interesting function" to scale the pattern down. `<<2` makes it half size, `<<3` makes it quarter size, etc. Gives you some interesting patterns.

Comment: Another one `y * 10000 / (x + 1)`

Comment: @WaqasIlyas Nice one! I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Using combinations of given tips, `(x+y)/2 * (x^y)` is pretty neat too

Comment: @EdvardM Neat indeed! I have edited the answer to include your comment.

Comment: I was messing around and `((x - y) * -1) * (x + y) / 2` seemed really cool too

Comment: @ChubbyCows Nice one! I have edited the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 12):

Please find here a suggestion with two approaches.

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    p := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for y := range p {
        p[y] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for x := range p[y] {
        p[y][x] = uint8(x^y)
        // p[y][x] = uint8(x*y)
        // p[y][x] = uint8((x+y)/2)
        }
    }
    return p
}

func _Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    p := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for i := 0; i < dy; i++ {
        p[i] = make([]uint8, dx)
    }
    for y := range p {
        for x := range p[y] {
            p[y][x] = uint8(x^y)
            // p[y][x] = uint8(x*y)
            // p[y][x] = uint8((x+y)/2)
        }
    }
    return p
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Comment: The OP has clearly mentioned that they aren't interested in just the code but want an explanation.. This answer does the exact opposite.

Comment: I found the code extremely useful.

Comment: The code might not help for OP but others

Comment: -1. Just providing code without any sort of explanation isn't the [best type of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and *especially* unhelpful when someone is asking for help on a tutorial exercise (i.e. trying to learn).